# ¿Es posible ejecutar un servlet desde una clase Thread?

Tags: java, jsp, hilos, servlets

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web con JSP. Esta aplicación tiene que mostrar el resultado de una consulta en una tabla. La dificultad es que esta se tiene que mostrar cuando se abre la aplicación (url), sin presionar ningún botón.
Pensé en hacer un Thread que se ejecute cada n tiempo y este llamase al servlet (controlador) para que realice lo demas (intancie la clase en la que esta la consulta a la base de datos y entregue los datos al jsp), pero en realidad no se si eso se puede hacer o si existe otra forma mas óptima de hacerlo.

Comment: "se tiene que mostrar cuando se abre la aplicación (url), sin presionar ningún botón"  No entiendo esto. Se muestra como respuesta a una request http o no?

Comment: el contenido se tiene que mostrar cuando te metes al index.jsp, este mostrará una tabla con el resultado de la consulta a la bd y se refresca cada n tiempo, sin tener que gatillar con bóton

Comment: Por qué no un simple auto refresh ? (Sigo sin entender por qué tanta insistencia en lo del "botón")

Comment: estimado, disculpa pero no se mucho java, es mi segundo proyecto recién, y estoy preguntando como hacerlo porque no se me ocurre, como comente antes, nombro el botón porque en el primer proyecto que hice con el botón gatillaba el servlet, en este no tiene que aparecer el botón, tiene que aparecer la información automáticamente cuando se abre el index.jsp.

Answer (score 1):

No es una buena idea, crear `Threads` para organizar la ejecución del código de una aplicación web es responsabilidad del contenedor, e.g. Tomcat.

Lo que puedes hacer es registrar tu servlet en `web.xml` para que escuche en una URL específica:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MiServlet</servlet-name>  // nombre del servlet
    <servlet-class>EsteEsMiServlet</servlet-class>  // clase del servlet
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MiServlet</servlet-name>   // nombre del servlet
    <url-pattern>/ruta</url-pattern>  // URL asignada al servlet
</servlet-mapping>
```

De esta forma cada que entras a `/ruta` el servlet se va a ejecutar, sin necesidad de presionar un botón u otra acción del usuario, siempre que el servlet sobrescriba el método `doGet`.

Comment: una consulta, 
<url-pattern>/ruta</url-pattern>  // URL asignada al servlet te refieres al jsp?

Comment: he puesto  <jsp:include page="/servlet/ServletConsultData" flush="true" />
si bien no se cae el jsp, este no muestra el resultado de la consulta

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo tener un Servlet que provea la información que necesitas vía JSON y hacer polling desde tu vista mediante Ajax para refrescar el contenido.

Te dejo un ejemplo de ambos.

Servlet que soporte llamadas ajax (puede ser cualquier servlet en realidad, el nombre es solo como demostración):

```
@WebServlet("/ajax/ajaxServlet")
public class AjaxServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        DataService dataService = new DataService();
        //método que obtiene los datos desde base de datos u otro
        List<Data> dataList = dataService.getData();
        //Obtenemos el escritor de la respuesta
        //para escribir el contenido de la respuesta manualmente
        Writer writer = response.getWriter();
        //escribimos los datos de la variable data como JSON
        writer.write(codificaEnJson(dataList));
    }

    private String codificaEnJson(Object o) {
        //código para codificar un objeto como JSON...
    }
}
```

Página web que realiza llamadas ajax utilizando poll mediante [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Uso de ajax</title>
    <!--
        Se asume que tienes jquery en tu proyecto
        y se encuentra en una ruta como
        Web Resources/js/jquery.js
        Cambia la ruta adecuadamente
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //función que hace poll
        (function poll() {
           //se llama a Timeout para ejecutar una acción
           //cada 
           setTimeout(function() {
              $.ajax({
                 url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax/ajaxServlet", //URL del servlet
                 success: function(data) {
                    //función para armar la tabla desde los valores
                 },
                 dataType: "json",
                 complete: poll //al finalizar, se vuelve a llamar a la función poll de manera que es eterno
              });
           }, 30000); //se ejecuta cada 30 segundos, puedes configurarlo al tiempo que requieras
        })();
    </script>

    <!-- la tabla vacía, lista para recibir los datos desde el JSON -->
    <table id="tabla">
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Para convertir un objeto a JSON, puedes utilizar [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) o [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). Aquí un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo con Jackson:

```
private String codificaEnJson(Object o) {
    //código para codificar un objeto como JSON...
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
}

ObjectMapper mapper;

public void init(ServletConfig config)
      throws ServletException {
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Comment: Luiggi no cuento con jquery en mi proyecto, solo cuento con el servlet que hace la consulta a la bd y el jsp que tendria que mostrar el resultado, me encuentro un poco perdida con el tema de ajax, jamas lo he tocado y me encuentro un poco confundida con respecto al llamado de : jquery.js, que tiene que contener eso?

Comment: ¿No cuentas con jquery en tu proyecto? Pues es una buena oportunidad para que lo coloques y aprendas :D. Como mencionas que el JSP debe auto refrescarse cada N tiempo, lo mejor es realizar esa labor con Ajax. El nombre "jquery.js" es solo de referencia, al final es un archivo JavaScript que contiene la librería jquery. No sé si trabajas en un proyecto universitario o de trabajo, te recomiendo que comentes las alternativas con tu instructor y que te comente cuál sería la mejor.

Comment: es laboral, soy la unica persona que programa, por ello es que no tengo a quien mas preguntarle

Comment: Comprendo mejor. ¿Lo que necesitas es que la página se auto refresque como en este ejemplo: [poll en primefaces, mira el contador 0 1 2 ...](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml) (no te estoy sugiriendo que utilices PrimeFaces en absoluto) o que al hacer click en un botón la página se pueda actualizar?

Comment: lo que necesito que la pag se autorefresque sola cada 2 minutos, por decir un tiempo, sin botón, tengo la estructura así:
ServletConsultData.java realiza la cosulta a la bd, la cual me trae un LinkedList, esta tiene que retornar el resultado a index.jsp (la pag principal), claramente en estos momentos cuando me meto a index.jsp, no muestra nada y por lo que usted me indica es bueno hacerlo con ajax

Comment: Correcto. Si ese es tu escenario, deberías utilizar ajax y poll, tal como se muestra en el enlace que puse en el comentario anterior. Te recomiendo revisar un poco de jQuery para que puedas realizar las peticiones ajax. El ejemplo de aquí es fácilmente adaptable. Si tienes más dudas, lo podemos revisar vía chat luego.

Comment: hola Luiggi, trate de adaptar el codigo que me diste como ejemplo, si bien no me arroja error, este no me muestra los resultados, es posible discutirlo por chat?
saludos